Person changing diaper with tongs
I am looking for the title of a movie that features a scene where a person changes a diaper with personal protective equipment on and tongs. 
The movie's language is English and was I believe it was released some time after 1985. 

Perhaps "Mr. Mom" starring Michael Keaton? Here's a relevant clip:



